# Need a simple way to index queries from page content in JAVA

Tags: java, indexing

I have access to page content in my JAVA class and would like to index queries in simple way in JAVA to get some queries out of the page content. The queries i am getting are independent and from the page content.

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/)?

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: @Kartik: SolR is a text indexing framework, which allows a user to process documents which can be later be searched through queries. This, I think, is pretty much what the OP is after.